# Are wall air vents a potential problem?

Tags: heating, air-conditioning, central-heating, central-air, heat-pump

A house I'm looking at has A/C vents in the walls, rather than in the ceiling or floor. I've never lived in a house with air ducts in the walls. Can I expect to have problems?

The house was built in the 70's, is on a concrete slab, and had a new heat pump put in three years ago.

Comment: Are those return vents? Top or bottom of the wall?  Either way, there won't be any airflow problems just because they are on the wall as long as you don't block them.

Comment: I've always had houses with the vents in the walls without issues. If they are in exterior walls (usually cold air returns) you might have insulation gaps and/or a little heat loss.

Comment: @Ethereal There aren't any other vents in the rooms, so I wouldn't think these would be return vents. In most rooms they are about a foot from the floor. In one or two rooms they are closer to the ceiling.